# How to pass an array of structures through Postback? 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following structure:

```
private struct S_indiv
{
    public int[] x;
    public int s;

    public S_indiv(int[] p1, int p2)
    {
        x = p1;
        s = p2;
    }
}
```

and array:

```
private static S_indiv[] ind;
```

How can I pass this array through Postback?

Comment: Do you mean keep it from your initial page and reconstruct it on the post back?

Comment: Pass it from where? Pass it to where?

Comment: Is your goal to then use it in javascript on the client side?

Comment: If you are trying to access from Page 2, anything from Page 1 you may want to do cross-page-posting. Refer http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-make-Cross-Page-Postback-in-ASP-Net.aspx

Comment: Static variables keep their values across postbacks. They are application-wide and have the same value on each page-instance across all sessions.

Comment: @Tejs, @John Saunders I need to keep it after button's click within 1 page

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Then I write "ind[i].s += weight[ind[i].x[j], ind[i].x[j + 1]];" I receive System.NullReferenceException:"Object reference not set to an instance of the object."

Comment: Decorate it with [Serializable()] and persist it via ViewState?

Comment: @DmitryB: i cannot see where you've instantiated the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment response, it sounds like you just want to keep it around for that single page lifecycle. If so, all you need to do is make a member variable on your page class:

```
protected S_indiv _myData;
```

If you create or load it in your button event, simply assign to that member variable instead. Then, for the rest of that lifecycle (including OnPreRender, etc), you can access that member variable and get the data.

If that is not what you want, please clarify with a timeline how you want to use this data.